# customizing the facebook registration widget with javascript

Tags: facebook, widget, customization

Is anyone aware of any restrictions Facebook places on modifying the look and feel of their registration widget?

We'd like to use the FB Registration widget on one of our pages, and then use jQuery to hide certain divs, text, etc. to make it a bit more compact and fit aesthetically better into our site.

Is is 'legal' or acceptable to do? I'm attempting to read through all of their documents to find out, but if someone already knows, that would really help.

tia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook uses iframes to load the registration plugin on your website. So there is no way you can change the looks of it with css or jQuery.

You can just customize however you want according to guidelines present here.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

Comment: Thanks Katti. Even the FBML version utilizes iframes?

Comment: FBML is no longer supported by fb. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/